# Electricity gone off while shrinking database, how can I recover my database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, data-recovery

While executing a shrink on a 25GB database, the electricity has gone down, and I can't access my database. It shows as "In Recovery".

How can I recover it?

Comment: Wait for the database server to finish rolling forward and back the committed and uncommitted transactions, respectively.

Comment: But the database stopped because the electricity is gone off. but the database is inaccessible, it says (I Recovery).

Comment: What is the current status of the database? Have a look in `sys.databases`, not the UI. There's a possibility you've run out of space on the data drive. You need to make space for the recovery to finish.

Comment: BTW, 25GB is not very huge. It's not even large.

Comment: I wasn't going to go there, @Mitch.

Comment: If in recovery, it should take some time and then go on line.

Comment: Yes, "In Recovery" means this - the server is working on getting it back online. Alternative - well - kill the db, apply the backup you took RIGHT BEFORE DOING THE SHRINK. You DID take a backup before suck a heavy operation, or? ;)

Comment: Real Men don't need no backups or appropriately sized uninterruptable power supplies. We can rewrite inode tables with a piece of magnetite and an old sewing needle. ;^)

Comment: Take this as a lesson to ALWAYS make a backup before performing any major operation on anything.

Answer (score 3):

Look into the sql server logs to see how much percent has been recovered. Find any errors in sql server logs as well as eventviewer.

If the situation does not improves in sometime, you may need to take the db into emergency mode to see what actually happened.